# Odd behavior of cron on @reboot

Tags: bash, cron

On Debian 8 after adding `@reboot`-line to crontab there are some strange results. All actions are performed by root.

`crontab -l` shows `@reboot /root/startup.sh`

*startup.sh* (+x rights):

```
#!/bin/bash
dhclient eth0
iptables-restore < /root/ipt
echo test > /tmp/startup.log
```

After reboot I can see in */var/log/syslog* something like `(root) CMD (/root/startup.sh)` and there is word "test" in */tmp/startup.log*. But dhclient and iptables did not work.
If I run the script manually all three lines give the result (i.e. ip address is received and iptables are restored).

How do I make it work through cron?

Comment: Perhaps it's a matter of timing - shouldn't those kinds of things be done via the network service's pre-up / post-up hooks?

Comment: @steeldriver Indeed, it's most probably a matter of timing. But the main reason why I didn't use those hooks was that the interface is not configured via `auto` because it entails another problem: boot hangs about 15 secs on LSB job "raise network interfaces". So given this problem, neither cron nor hooks can help in such case?

Comment: `@reboot` means "when cron is started". This may be before the network devices exist.

Comment: @wurtel Not quite true about "cron is started", but "when it first starts". Cron looks at the existence of file */var/run/crond.reboot* to check if it runs on actual reboot. But the question of the existence of network devices at cron's startup is still relevant, need to deal